# H2 element is not on separate line

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS that I do not understand. The `h2` tag is appended to the previous element, rather than being on a seporate line.

[image]

My code makes use of the CSS properties `position`, `float` and `clear`. Perhaps the problem is something to do with that?

I have tried to disabling various CSS styles in Chrome developer without luck.

Here is my minified code example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #3</label>
  </div>
</section>
<h2>Heading</h2>
```

Comment: Why downvote? Can you explain? I did investigation, I provided source code and runnable sample to easily reproduce the trouble.

Comment: probably the parent container is the cause of this behavior, check them.

Comment: What do you see? I can see the same behaviour as in screenshot (chrome).

Comment: @LeosLiterak: the codepen example is incomplete. But there is probably `float: left` on `.sign-up-form__input` (add `clear: left` after) or nested `div`s (add `overflow: hidden` to `.sign-up-form__input`).

Comment: I created this sample again and  tested it in Chrome anonymous mode. I still can reproduce it,

Comment: Thank you panther. Clear worked. I will delete this downvoted question later ..

Comment: It could be caused by checkbox CSS: .atoms__checkbox {
  width: 9em;
  float: left;
}

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not a codepen. I am unable to reproduce your problem with the supplied code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this

```
.sign-up-form__input {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This will make sure that floated child elements are completely wrapped by the `.sign-up-form__input` element, and thereby also solve your problem since the `h2` will be moved down below the preceding `.sign-up-form__input`element.

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: left;` to the `<h2>` that you are having trouble with.

```css
h2 {
  clear: left;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Radio #3</label>
  </div>
</section>
<h2>Heading</h2>
```

Comment: Your solution works as well, upvoted. Thank you.